# How to save this button status in a localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that mute all sounds in my page and I have other that unmute it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   /*** Mute all ***/
   $('#mute_all').on('click',function(){

      /*** Mute all video and audio on page ***/
      $('body video, body audio').each(function(){
         /*** Do it here globally ***/
         $(this).prop('muted', true);
      });

   });

   /*** UnMute all ***/
   $('#unmute_all').on('click',function(){

      /*** Un Mute all video and audio on page ***/
      $('body video, body audio').each(function(){
         /*** Do it here globally ***/
         $(this).prop('muted', false);
      });

   });


});
```

The problem is when I refresh the page, changes arent persist. How can I do it with a LocalStorage?

Thanks!!

Comment: use document.cookie

Comment: You tried `localStorage.setItem("name", "value")` and `localStorage.getItem("name")` ? I'm sure google would have told you this if you asked

Comment: Yes! I tried! Sorry if I didn't say that in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time user clicks mute/unmute button, save their choice in a `localStorage` variable using `localStorage.setItem("name", "value")`. You can save only string values.

Now on every page load, you should first check if that variable has specific value in user's `localStorage` using `localStorage.getItem("name")` and configure things accordingly.

[You can read more about localStorage here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // first check localStorage if any previous choice is stored
   var muted = localStorage.getItem("muted");
   if( muted === "true" ){
      muteAll();
   }

   /*** Mute all ***/
   $('#mute_all').on('click',function(){    
      muteAll();    
   });

   /*** UnMute all ***/
   $('#unmute_all').on('click',function(){

      /*** Un Mute all video and audio on page ***/
      $('body video, body audio').each(function(){
         /*** Do it here globally ***/
         $(this).prop('muted', false);
      });
      // save user's current choice in localStorage
      localStorage.setItem("muted", "false");

   });


});

function muteAll(){
     /*** Mute all video and audio on page ***/
      $('body video, body audio').each(function(){
         /*** Do it here globally ***/
         $(this).prop('muted', true);
      });
      // save user's current choice in localStorage
      localStorage.setItem("muted", "true");
}//muteAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the muted status in local storage on clicking the MuteAll. And check for its initial value in the document ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   function muteAll(){
    $('body video, body audio').each(function(){
         $(this).prop('muted', true);
      });
     window.localStorage.setItem('muted','true');
   }
   function unmuteAll(){
     $('body video, body audio').each(function(){

         $(this).prop('muted', false);
      });
     window.localStorage.setItem('muted','false');
   }

    $('#mute_all').on('click',mute_all);
   $('#unmute_all').on('click',unmute_all);
   var status=window.localStorage.getItem('muted')
   if(status && status=='true'){
    mute_all();
   }else{
    unmute_all(); //if required
   }
});
```

Comment: You should take your `window.localStorage.setItem('muted','false');` statements out of the `each` loop.

Answer (score 0):

1) set item like this

```
 $('#mute_all').on('click',function(){

   $('body video, body audio').each(function(){
     /*** Do it here globally ***/
     $(this).prop('muted', true);
  });

    localStorage.setItem("muted", "true")

  });
```

2) Get item like this

```
 localStorage.getItem("muted")
```

3) inside the document ready function check the local storage  and click the element using **click()**

```
     $(document).ready(function(){  
         var muted = localStorage.getItem("muted");
         if( muted === "true" ){
             $('#mute_all').click();
            }
       });
```